# How to get class object of a function in hooked function?

Tags: c++, qt, hook, interceptor

I recently started to work on application interception using `madhookc` hooking library.I am hooking the methods called in the application to do manipulation of text. At one point i got stuck and need your help.

I have a paragraph of text in which  in which some text is Bold and some is regular style. Now i want to differentiate the regular and bold text and do different operations on both.  I know that `QFont::setFamily(QString)`  function is called for each line of text that is going to be displayed.So i hooked `setFamily()`. Now i am able to get font family of the text ,but all text of the paragraph (i.e. regular and bold) has same font family. Now i want to check whether this text is bold or not, so for that i need a object of `QFont` class so that i can call it's `bold();` which returns true or false.    Ultimately i want this pointer of the `setFamily()` function.(Same as like we get `target` in `pointcut` of  `AspectJ` interception.)

```
void WINAPI newsetFamily( QString & family );
void (WINAPI *UnhooksetFamily)( QString & family );


void WINAPI newsetFamily ( QString & family )
{
     QFont *font=this_pointer;
     if(font->bold())
     {
          //do this
     }
     else
     {
           //do this
     }
}
```

Please help me  . Thanx in advance. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got my way !!!
After some research , i come to know that that current class object of a function is nothing but `this` pointer of the function, and this pointer can be exist only if the function belongs to some class.
    I also came to know that QT class functions follows various calling conventions.The class i am referring follows the `__fastcall` for its functions. `__fastcall` calling convention requires first 2 hidden parameters to be passed to function if you want to hook it successfully. So i passed `void *` (void pointers) as first 2 parameters of the function and it worked.
Then i came to know that first `void *` pointer is nothing but `this` pointer of the function. That's how i got my target.

solved code:

```
void (__fastcall *UnhooksetFamily)(  QFont *This,void *noUse,QString & family );


void __fastcall newsetFamily ( QFont *This,void *noUse,QString & family )
{
     QFont *font=This;
     if(font->bold())
     {
          //do this
     }
     else
     {
           //do this
     }
}
```